# Android App compatibility Issue- Testing and Release (Min sdk and target sdk and ActionBar)

Tags: android, compatibility

I'm new to Android development. I know this question is asked before. I've developed an Android application, tested it on OS Ver > 4.0.4 android phones. It worked fine. My SDK settings in the manifest file are below.

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Doing so, will it limit the audience for the application? I see that I cannot allow the users who has V < 3.0 because of the ActionBar. But, does the SDK versions have any compatibility issues? I'd like to keep a wider Audience to this app, but do not have bandwidth to test on all versions. Thanks.

I'm releasing app next month. What are the issues that I have to take care of when releasing in context of the app compatibility in the Android developer console?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A `minSdkVersion` value of 9 indicates that the app will be available for devices running Android 2.3 (Gingerbread). If you want to restrict it to devices running 3.0 and above, you have to have a `minSdkVersion` of 11.

If `ActionBar` is the only contentious issue preventing you from distributing to devices running Android version <3.0, you can use the [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) to make it available for Android versions 2.1 and above.

> I'd like to keep a wider Audience to this app, but do not have bandwidth to test on all versions.

I do not understand what you mean by "bandwidth", but if you really want to test it on all  versions, you can create emulators for each of these version and test it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Bandwidth as in, manpower. How about  releasing the app, what care should I take care of when releasing?

Comment: There is no substitute for testing. If you want to verify that it works on all versions, you need to test. Other than that, there's little to take care of. Also, take a look at the [Best Practices](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/index.html).